# Gilbert Tableview library display issue

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How can I remove the tableview from the display. The problem i am facing is that, when I create tableview and move back then the tableview is superimposed on the group.

I have tried

```
tableView:cleanUp()
```

to no avail.

Comment: Can you give us some more code? Try boiling it down to a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

let me try to summarize..

```
local a=display.newGroup()
//few text objects and button objects in it.on the same screen 
local resultList=tableView.newList{data=resultData}
```

so my current screen contains a tableviewList and few other button
and image controls or groups for corona
Important to stress list does not belong to any group.
now next part if i press android back button what i do is

```
transition.to(a,{alpha=0})
```

and same for other controls except for the list.
as i want new groups to show up.
i want to remove list from display.
i tried

```
resultList:cleanUp()
```

as mentioned in documentation,but doesnt work.Is it any clear?